# Correct width of main div in CSS

Tags: css, html

Let's say I want to create an HTML page with one main div that holds all the content. 
The div should hold other divs and be fixed in the center of the page like in the image.

How should I specify the width? In a % value or a value in `px?` What is the best practise?
And what should be the correct value? 
Please sorry if this has been covered before....

**Image is here**: [image]

**EDIT**
So much nice answers... Thank you all very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the content you will be presenting and what you want to do with it. You may choose to use a fixed width layout if there is no need for the content to expand, or if you want to keep the text/design constrained within the width of the DIV. Though, one thing you may want to consider is using a combination of percentage and fixed width. For example, you may choose for your DIV to be 95% of the page as long as the minimum width is not below 700px and the maximum width is not over 950px. The result of this is a DIV that will expand and contract within your specified constrains.

```
div#container { 
    width:95%; 
    max-width: 950px; 
    min-width: 700px; 
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use `px`

Cause the % will depend on the wide-screen of the user, so images could display bad

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your image but you can do that with two divs using percentages.

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">  
   <div id="inner">Your centered div</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
    width: 100%;
}

#inner {
    width: 50%; // whatever width you want - I can't see your image
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the div simply put left and right margins to `auto` on css.

Regarding the % or px, it would REALLY depend on the layout you are willing to code. If your layout was made thinking in a fluid layout, then you should use `%` but add a `max-width` so it would not stretch past `n px`.

For example:

You layout was made for a 1024px screen using 960px grid. But it would be cool to let it stretch a bit for 1280px screen users. So you put `width:100%;` and after ir, `max-width:1280px`.

So any user with bigger screen will see the layout for a 1280px.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use body `margin:0` and use container div with margin auto, and use pixel for content width and height.

```
<div class="container">

        <!-- HTML Content here -->
 </div>

.container{
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

Css float left and right control the flow of the div. if you want to place two divs, right and left, then use

```
.left-div {
   float: left;
   width:200px // use pixel to control width
   margin-left: 5px;
 }
.right-div {
   float: right;
   width:200px;
   margin-right: 5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Holding that main div in center position can be done with `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`.

Second:
I don't think, that there is a basic best practice, because the usability of variable with depends highly on the content itself.
One usable solution that covers both could be using fixed width depending on the device (desktop, table, phone) using media queries.